# finding anagrams considering all the words in english

Tags: python-2.7

```
words_ = load_words("C:\Users\Abdullah\Downloads\EOWL-v1.1.2\EOWL-v1.1.2\LF Delimited Format")

def find_all_anagrams(words, word):
    import itertools
    permuted_chars = []
    for i in range(2, len(word)+1):
        permuted_chars += itertools.permutations(word, i)
    permutations_list = ["".join(i) for i in permuted_chars]
    anagrams_list = [i for i in permutations_list if i in words]
    return anagrams_list
```

To find the anagrams of a given word i figured out this solution
I have the words list of 128,000 can any body suggest a better way
For loading the words:

```
from io import *
import string

def load_words(base_dir):
    words = []
    for i in string.uppercase:
        location = base_dir+"\\"+i+" Words.txt"
        with open(location, "rb+") as f:
            words += [x.rstrip() for x in f.readlines()]
    return words
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution?

Comment: takes about 20 seconds to complete execution

Comment: Looking for better solution, which is faster and has less time complexity

Comment: Your definition of an anagram seems a bit odd - you should be using strictly all of the letters in the `word`, I don't understand the `for i in ...` loop

Comment: For "abbeys" ["abbe","abbey","abbeys"] are anagrams. I used the for loop generate anagrams for varied size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a better way. Anagrams contain the same letters. So if you sort the word (by characters), you will get the same result. (eg: `mary` -> `amry`, `army` -> `amry`).

Using this trick, you can simply build a dictionary, where the sorted version is the key, and the list of anagrams is the value.

Comment: But how can we preserve the duplicates

Comment: dictionary internally does the set implementation for all the keys so for "mary","army"->"amry"---> is the key, last value for key will exist

Comment: "*a list of* anagrams"